# Is SQL IN more efficient than doing individual lookups?

Tags: sql

For example in the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE LastName IN ('Hansen','Pettersen', 'Smith')
```

Assuming LastName is indexed, is the single query more efficient than doing three separate queries on LastName?

Comment: The short answer is yes (1 network round trip instead of 3, 1 parse overhead instead of three, 1 travel of the index instead of 3). But the question really could be; have you tested it yourself? *[Don't just trust other people's answers, I may be wrong; test, validate, use imperical evidence ;)]*

Answer (score 2):

Doing a single query is faster than running several queries to retrieve the same amount of data, because you save on the number of network round-trips. In my experience, the number of roundtrips is usually the biggest killer of performance in multi-query scenarios.

Comparing to a single query with three *conditions*, like this,

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE LastName='Hansen' OR LastName='Pettersen' OR LastName='Smith'
```

is different: most optimizers figure out that it is the same as the `IN` query, so your performance stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you will create index in column it will affect your performance..
You can use non-clustered indices on any foreign key columns.

This will help you..

try to implement several queries like this some of with index and some of without index..
You will know difference..

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the answer is *probably* yes: As Dems said:

> 1 network round trip instead of 3, 1 parse overhead instead of three, 1 travel of the index instead of 3

But that's not true for the general case. Examples:

- Some databases don't allow arbitrary numbers of elements in the `IN` clause. Oracle limits you to 1000. So even if it would be faster to do in one query, you can't always.
- If the expression after the `IN` is a sub query it can be faster to run that sub query, process the results in your app and build a second query with a value list instead (usually because of index and/or type casting issues).

Comment: Good point about the limit of elements, but using a sub-query in a single statement is usually faster than running the sub-query as a separate query (at least with DBMS that have a decent query optimizer)

Comment: As I said: "it **can** be faster" but that's not **always** true, contrary to intuition. In some case, the optimizer generates a completely brain-dead plan (like doing two full table scans instead of reading the five results of the sub-query into a temporary table and join over that).

Comment: two full table scans might actually be faster than using a temporary table and a join. Which DBMS are you refering to? I don't think I have seen this kind of behaviour with Oracle or PostgreSQL

Comment: I've seen this in Oracle and in DB2. In the Oracle case, the problem was that in one table, the column type was `DATE` and in the subquery, `TIMESTAMP` was returned. In this case, Oracle decided to ignore the existing indices and scan the tables instead (all 120 million rows).

Comment: Ah! The perils of implicit typecasting - always good for bad plans. Hardly any DBMS will use an index for a column if the value to compare to is not of the same type. If you had changed the sub-query to return a date instead (e.g. using `cast`) I bet the plan would have been better.